# How do I properly use notifyDataSetChanged in my code?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am populating a ListView with a custom SimpleCursorAdapter.

I have a delete function that deletes a person from the database that is backing the ListView.

I cannot figure out where to put `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that my list refreshes to show the person has been removed.

I am using a SwipeRefreshLayout that will show that the person has been removed if I swipe, but I would prefer if the list would update automatically when the person was removed.

Where would I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my code?

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements TabChanger{

    private View rootView;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout personSwipeRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        personSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_swipe_refresh);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        drawThePersonView();

        personSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(Constants.RED), Color.parseColor(Constants.ORANGE), Color.parseColor(Constants.YELLOW), Color.parseColor(Constants.GREEN), Color.parseColor(Constants.BLUE), Color.parseColor(Constants.INDIGO), Color.parseColor(Constants.VIOLET));
        personSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                personSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                drawThePersonView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawThePersonView(){
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        Cursor personCursor = myDBHelper.getPersonsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id","studentID","firstname","lastname","object_id"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.person_number_textview, R.id.person_id_textview};
        FragmentManager fragMan = this.getFragmentManager();
        CustomSimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter = new CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(this, fragMan, getActivity(), R.layout.person_layout, personCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        // Replace the _id column with a person count
        mySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                String counter = Integer.toString((cursor.getPosition()+1));
                TextView modifiedTextView = (TextView) view;
                if(columnIndex == 0){
                    modifiedTextView.setText(counter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_row);

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);
    }

    // Pass me a tab index (see Constants.java) and I'll return a refrence to that tab.
    private String getFragmentTag(int tagID){
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + tagID;
    }

    @Override
    public void changeTab(int tab) {
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
    }
}
```

**CustomSimpleCursorAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        // Set alternating rows to different colors.
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.WHITE));
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.LIGHTGREY));
        }

        // When the delete icon is clicked, delete from the database.
        // Then, refresh the view.
        ImageView deleteButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.person_delete_button);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                final String personID = cursor.getString(1);

                Toast statusToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Deleting person " + personID + " ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                statusToast.show();

                DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                myDBHelper.deletePerson(personID);

            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you trying to get with calling notifyDataSet changed that your aren't seeing? By recreating your list adapter in pull to refresh the list will update itself with the new list already.

Comment: I have a list of people. When I click the delete icon and the person is deleted, I want the ListView to refresh, showing the person is no longer there.

Comment: Whenever you change the dataset that is backing the list, be it a List or a database, you can call notifyDatasetChange() in order to refrest the list.

Comment: Yes, but where in the code that I posted, do I call notifyDatasetChange?

Comment: myDBHelper.deletePerson(personID);
Does this deletes the person from your DB or also from the adapter?

If it does not delete from adapter, delete from there too.
Once that is done, call notifyDataSetChanged()
If supported by your adapter, use notifyItemRemoved() instead.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html creating a cursor loader will automatically reload the cursor and update the associated UI elements whenever the data is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919239/i-cannot-figure-out-how-to-correctly-use-notifydatasetchanged-within-my-app/36920073) Stack Overflow post that did the trick for me. I am posting the answer I used in case it might help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the Android documentation:

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

So whenever you make a change to the data, you can call this method in order to notify the View, that the dataset has changed and it should re-draw.

For further info refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: So, where in the code that I posted would I place the notifyDatasetChange() method call?

Comment: The end of the deleteButton click listener method.

Comment: Thanks ... I tried it, but the list didn't refresh.

Comment: Allright, in that case, you need to recreate the cursor after deleting the person from the database and then call notifyDatasetChange().

Comment: Well, in your code you create it using Cursor personCursor = myDBHelper.getPersonsCursor(), so you can use the same code, to create it again and set it to the adapter.

Comment: So, I just make the same call from my CustomSimpleCursorAdapter in the same place you suggested placing the notifyDatasetChange method call?

Comment: Yes. You delete the person from the database, then, you get the cursor from the database, set it to the adapter and then tell the adapter you have changed the data, and it should do something about it, using the notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: Re-creating the cursor requires variables that I do not have available to me within the cursor itself (e.g., [this android example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews))